Preview uploaded HEIC/HEIF files in Safari Browser
I know Safari officially supports these formats, but I'm having trouble trying to display these images on the page when a user uploads them to the page. Can the browser render HEIC/HEIF files directly in DOM?
I tried to display with  tag and used background-image css rule
